# Using Java Netscape Directory LDAP API and binary filter values

Tags: java, ldap

I'm trying to find out if anyone is familiar how to use a binary value in a search filter against the userCertificate attribute in LDAP.  I know how to do this with the old JNDI API but I'm curious if anyone can help me figure it out in the Netscape Directory SDK (netscape.ldap).

JNDI API example:

```
byte[] userCert = Base64.decodeBase64(base64Certificate);
Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<String, String>();
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, ldapURL);
env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, username);
env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);
InitialDirContext context = new InitialDirContext(env);
SearchControls controls = new SearchControls();
controls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);
controls.setReturningAttributes(fetchArray);
Enumeration<SearchResult> results = context.search(baseDN, "userCertificate={0}", new Object[] {userCert}, controls);
```

What I would *like* to do is use the following API, but it doesn't get any results while the code above does:

```
byte[] userCert = Base64.decodeBase64(base64Certificate);
LDAPConnection ld = new LDAPConnection();
ld.connect(ldapURL, ldapPort);

ld.authenticate(username, password);

LDAPSearchResults results = ld.search(baseDN, LDAPConnection.SCOPE_SUB, "(userCertificate;binary=" + base64Certificate + ")",
                fetchArray, false);
```

I tried with/without the ;binary modifier and have tried both binary and base64 values.  However, what *does* work is if I write a custom method to convert a byte array to "\xx" string format.  That seems a bit hackish and probably slow though so I'm wondering if there's an API-native way to do a binary search like this.

Thanks.

Comment: If you're going to switch LDAP APIs, the Netscape API is ten years old and long out of of any maintenance activity that I can see. You might be better off looking at the UnboundID API: @TerryGardner regularly spruiks it here and at least it does appear to be under maintenance. If you can't do that, have a good look at the LDAP Search Filters RFC.

Comment: Thanks.  This Netscape LDAP API is already in use on the project so I'm having to do this one search with the one-off JNDI setup right now.  I'd love to switch to a more modern API but I'm working with what we got. :)  I'll see if I can glean anything from the RFC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a completely different thing if you want to compose filters for attributes whose data types appear as binary hex values (the according data type is often referred to as 'Octet String').

If you are going to filter for such binary attributes, it is mandatory to declare every single byte that has to be compared in hex code. For instance, if you search for objects with the attribute 'Inventory' which has the value 0x01AAF5EF, then the appropriate filter will have to read:

```
(Inventory=\01\aa\f5\ef)
```

Unfortunately, wildcard search is not allowed when searching for binary attributes!

[Try this link for more](http://www.ldapexplorer.com/en/manual/109010000-ldap-filter-syntax.htm)

Comment: Yeah that is what I had to do to get it to work at all - convert to the 'Octet String' format.  I guess the JNDI implementation does this automatically.